# Cannot Access specific element in XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my first post on here and I am hoping someone will be able to help me as I have been racking my brain for ages trying to access a particular element in my XML using my existing XSL. I have searched the site and have come close to finding the answer but it was never exactly what I was looking for.

The new element I am trying to process is , ideally I am looking to be able to reference the 'Label' within NOTE to extract the corresponding value. For example, in the below XML I would like to be able to extract the value of the "Unit" label which is KT and store that in `<UOM>`.

The XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TYRE xmlns="gapi-tyre-com" Action="Update">
   <INSTSPECIFIER SEQ="10000"/>
   <TERM Default="" Desc="" Label="Execution" Type="string">MTT</TERM>
   <ANNOTATIONS>
      <NOTE Label="CP">2013-12-03T15:38:48.931</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="CPR">UK</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="Unit">KT</NOTE>
      <NOTE Label="UnitID">10000554</NOTE>
   </ANNOTATIONS>
</TYRE>
```

The current XSL I have is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Version 1.0.001 -->

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:g="gapi-tyre-com"
exclude-result-prefixes="g">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" doctype-public="importFile" doctype-system="importer.dtd"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="importFile">
        <xsl:attribute name="source">T</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="template">default</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="g:TYRE"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>       

<xsl:template match="g:TYRE">
  <TYREImport>
    <xsl:choose> 
        <xsl:when test="@Action = 'Remove'">
            <audit>DELETE</audit>
        </xsl:when>         
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <audit>NEW</audit>
        </xsl:otherwise>        
    </xsl:choose>
            <type>F</type>
    <period>H</period>
    <ABCD>D</ABCD>
    <TYREtype2>P</TYREtype2>
    <mt>F</mt>      
    <memo1> MTT , <xsl:value-of select="g:INSTSPECIFIER/@SEQ"/></memo1>             
  </TYREImport>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be much appreciated on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show the value of `<NOTE Label="Unit">`?

```
  <TYREImport>
     ....
     <UOM>
        <xsl:value-of select="g:ANNOTATIONS/g:NOTE[@Label='Unit']" />
     </UOM>
  </TYREImport>
```

Comment: Thats the one I was looking for... I think  I was going down the wrong route using xsl:for-each. Thank you very much for your quick response and I'm sorry if that was a bit too easy. Happy New Year!